# How to display Droplist Field Value in Page and Edit in Experience Editor?

Tags: sitecore-client, experience-editor

I Have a Field of Droplist type. The source of the field is of a Folder under which two items are present.
In the droplist field we can select the name of the two Item present in the source folder.
I need to display in page the value of the Droplist and make it editable in Experience Editor. I need to click on the field in page and the field source  will come.Whatever i select will get updated in the corresponding Droplist field.

I cannot change the type to droplink.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have written a Blog post on this that could be a good read. You will find it here "https://everydaysitecore.home.blog/2020/04/29/change-droplist-field-source-item-value-using-sitecore-experience-editor/". This explains on how, when you need to use the droplist field, but still using sitecore experience editor, have a way to edit the value of the item pointed to my the droplist field rather than the droplist field value itself.

Answer (score 1):

This is the case where you need to use `Field editor button`, basically you can define a field editor button in `core` database, you can define the fields you want to be edited, then associate this button with your rendering, following are the steps:

1. Switch to core database and navigate to this path: **/sitecore/content/Applications/WebEdit/Custom Experience Buttons**
2. Specify an icon, a header, Fields (the field(s) names pipe-separated you want to edit) and tooltip.
3. Switch back to `master` database and in `Experience Editor Buttons` navigate to your button and select it.

Now when you're in Experience Editor, you will find a button that you can use to edit the droplist field, as example see below:

[image]

Comment: This is not working, because i am not able to display the field in page. The custom button works on the field shown in pae

Comment: so you mean the field is not on the page item or the data source item of your rendering?

Comment: the field is in the page item, how do i show it in page through  the model and the view that is responsible for displaying the page item?

Comment: maybe you can edit the question and add snippets of your code, but you Sitecore should show you a popup with dropdown to edit your field if it found in your data source item or context item based on the steps I provided above.